# Web-service to organise multiple web accounts interactively

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking for a web service (website) or a tool to interactively organise all my web accounts (such as forum, mail, and many other).

The problem is having 100+ different kind of web accounts of which some expire after 6-12 months of non-usage reasons, so organising them would help me to not forget about them by once-a-year dummy log-in. Ideally the service would have some additional recipes/rules (such as auto-login to test if the account is alive, etc.).

There is a tool like KeePassX, however it allows me to manage my accounts in a not-interactive way, so I can't really do anything with them (apart of the list). So I'm rather looking something more closer to [IFTTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT).

Comment: KeePassX has URL entries and lists expired entries, so I'm not entirely clear why you can't just go through the list from time to time and visit each URL in turn.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's very inconvenient, as you've to keep your KeePassX all the time up-to-date (for example if you change your password, you've to remember to update your file). Also it won't log-in on your-behalf (or something similar) and won't notify you before expire date without opening it first. Secondly I'm not using it very often.

Comment: I use KeePass (and KeeFox), not KeePassX, but I assume autotype is the same, so that should be fairly straightforward: click the URL to open, hit the autotype hotkey, go back to KeePassX, update expiry date. As far as expiry, just set it for, say, a week shorter than you actually need, and you're done.